# How to match this expression via regex?

Tags: regex

How can I match lines like the following:

```
 SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText 
SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText.
SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText.
SomeText SomeText :
SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText  (BlockID: 12345,TestCaseID: 12345, 1)
```

What I want from this is the whole part before (BlockID: 12345,TestCaseID: 12345, 1)
Another part I want is the 12345 of BlockID, and another one for TestCaseID

I have tried the following to mark all lines but I don't know further:

```
(?:[^\n]*(\n*))+.*
```

Comment: Something like [`(?s)(.*?)\s*\(BlockID:\s*(\d+),TestCaseID:\s*(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xI3iJ2/1)?

Comment: Or [`(?s)(.*?)\s*\(BlockID:\s*(\d+),TestCaseID:\s*((?:,?\s*\d+)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/xI3iJ2/2)?

Answer (score 0):

Everything until BlockID:

```
([\S\s]*)(?=\(BlockID)
```

12345 from BlockID:

```
(?:BlockID: )([0-9]{5})
```

12345, 1 from TestCaseID:

```
(?:TestCaseID: )([0-9]{5}, [0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the types of actual input you have I can recommend something like

```
(.+)\\(BlockID: (\\d+),TestCaseID: (\\d+), 1\\)
```

which means:

- Capture a sequence of characters (including new lines since we'll add the `DOTAL` flag) of length 1 or more,
- until you reach `BlockID:`,
- at which point capture a sequence of 1 or more digits,
- followed by `,TestCaseID:`,
- then again capture a sequence of 1 or more digits,
- followed by `, 1)`.

Here it is in work:

```
public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = " SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText \r\n" + 
        "SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText.\r\n" + 
        "SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText.\r\n" + 
        "SomeText SomeText :\r\n" + 
        "SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText  (BlockID: 12345,TestCaseID: 12345, 1)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\(BlockID: (\\d+),TestCaseID: (\\d+), 1\\)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText
>   SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText  SomeText.
>   SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText.
>   SomeText SomeText :
>   SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText SomeText
>   12345
>   12345